# Access To Hard Disk Data Using Wamp

Tags: wamp

i'm developing a local host web site in WAMP server and it can accessed remotely. i created a index.html file and i have 3 partition on my computer. for example i have a zip file called a.zip in E:\ Partition and i installed the wamp server in C Partition. i created a link in the index.html and i want when user clicking on this link, the file start to download. i tried this code in my HTML,but it doesn't working :

```
<a href="E:\a.zip">Link</a>
```

when i'm clicking on the link, no thing happens.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. What happens is that, you're effectively pointing to a file that's on the local filesystem of the computer you're browsing the website with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make E:\a.zip accessible to anyone using WAMP, you need to make it accessible using localhost/folder/file.

By default, only files inside public_html are accesable using WAMP, since you are linking E:\ drive, it won't work. Read up on "Adding a virtual directoy using WAMP".